# Google Drive error using intent. The file could not be downloaded. please save the file to your local storage and then try to open it. Samsung android

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, samsung-mobile

I have some pdf links displayed in my app and I am using the below code to open the pdf using other apps installed on the phone.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
```

One of our employees has google drive installed on her Samsung phone, when she try to open the pdf link " The file could not be downloaded. please save the file to your local storage and then try to open it" this error is coming. It's working on all other devices except for this particular device. Any work around for this error ?

Comment: Tell your url..

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for your reply. That's an internal URL and I can't share it here.

Comment: We are not interested in your internal affairs. But you should post an url that looks like yours so we get the idea. Does it start with ftp://.. ?

Comment: @blackapps it starts with http://<web-site-name>/etc/etc.pdf.

Comment: Which app normally downloads the pdf? And which app will display it? You are not giving very much info.

Comment: @blackapps I am setting application/pdf in the intent so that any app which could open the pdf..user can choose from the apps promoted by the OS. Basically google drive opens these PDFs.

Comment: You have not told much about that particular device either. And try to use another pdf viewer on that phone.

Comment: If the protocol is http on Android 10 it can not be downloaded i think.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for the help. I will look into the phone version and try to use another pdf viewer.

Comment: @blackapps I am using one plus which has android 10 and I am able to view the pdfs.

Comment: @blackapps That person is using Samsung Galaxy S9+ running Android 10